# Reading changes in JSON file using JS

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, syslog-ng

I'm trying to read an updating JSON file from syslog-ng. Currently, syslog, a logging software, is set to continually append a JSON file with logs of the data I want. I'm displaying the data on my cyber attack map only for only 30 seconds until it's not needed anymore. I can read the file and parse what I need, but is there a way to, over time, read & parse only the most recent additions to the file?

Sample code:

```
//Assume JSON output = {attack source, attack destination, attack type}

//Required modules
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
var fs = require('fs');

//Creates readable stream for JSON file parsing
var stream = fs.createReadStream( 'output.json', 'utf8'),
    parser = JSONStream.parse(['source', 'dest', 'type']);

//Send read data to parser function
stream.pipe(parser);

//Intake data from parser function
parser.on('data', function (obj) {

    //Do something with the object
    console.log(obj);
  });
```

I'm using JSONStream to avoid having to read the whole log file into memory, JSONstream should still be able to parse the bits I want, but is there a method to only read changes after the original reading is complete?

Comment: if the json is really big, then you cannot split it, to do piece by piece parsing, you have to wait until full file is loaded to any stream or buffer

Comment: Hmm, this might be what I was looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-watch-stream

Comment: @DickensAS Can you explain in greater detail? I thought streaming the JSON would make it so reading the whole file to memory wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @DickensAS So would it be better to just read the entire file into memory? Wouldn't I run into memory problems?

Comment: what is the content looks like, is it a full json starts with a curling brace and ends with a curling brace ? or it is a new line de-limited multi json log file ?

Comment: Full JSON, starts and ends w/ curling braces.

Comment: does it looks like this uniformly, https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/blob/master/test/fixtures/all_npm.json

Comment: yes, very similar @DickensAS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211944/discussion-between-dickens-a-s-and-thomas-c).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code example provided in the library

[JSONStream Test code](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/blob/master/test/fixtures/all_npm.json)

You don't have to wait for the end, you can use the callback to do your work object by object

But the file structure should suite the library expectation as the files given in the folder

Example file [all_npm.json](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/blob/master/test/fixtures/all_npm.json)